# Updating rake gem to 10.0.3 outputs errors when pushing to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rake, rack

In my Rails app, I just updated the rake gem from 0.9.2.2. to 10.0.3, and rack from 1.4.1 to 1.4.3.

Prior to updating the gems, when I did a `git push` to Heroku my output would just look like this:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
```

(not concerned with the asset precompilation failure; I know why that is happening)

But now after updating the gems, when I push to Heroku I get this error:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `new'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__769451004690509272__prepare__527462282276125186__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_15ju6av9wl7bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
```

What is going on here? Is this something I need to fix? The app still seems to run fine, but I'd like to know what is causing the error at least. Is rake just more verbose in version 10.0.3 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the newer version of rake is just being more verbose. If you don’t need to access the database to compile your assets (usually you won’t), you can add

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

to `config/application.rb`.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar for more information.

Comment: Yes, I decided to go this route. I do not need database access at pre-compilation time (which seems to be what my error was), so turning off app initialization during asset pre-compilation seems sensible.